# UTC datetime of a specific LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

*Example:* Get UTC datetime of *2020-06-04 12.00 AM IST*

My application needs to compare the current datetime with the saved access-start time for login reasons. Since UTC avoids timezone issues, the given access-start datetime is converted to an UTC datetime and stored in my database.

*Case 1:* Access-start datetime: Current timestamp, which can be converted to UTC and stored.

*Case 2:* Access-start time: *2020-06-04 12.00 AM IST*, where I'm not sure how to convert it to UTC.

Comment: If you feel to downvote, please add a comment so that I could improve myself. Thanks.

Comment: *"get UTC time of 2020-06-04 12.00am IST"*, the `IST` at the end is a timezone, thus, what you have there cannot be a `LocalDateTime`. Could it be a `ZonedDateTime` what you are talking about?

Comment: yes, I used OffsetDateTime. I used this to check if the ZonedDateTime can be converted to UTC
OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(), ZoneOffset.UTC)

Comment: I've edited the question, including tags, so more people can find it and understand your problem. Please let me know, if I've edited the question so much that it's not asking what *you* want to know anymore.

Comment: thanks @akuzminykh for helping me out

Answer (score 2):

```
    OffsetDateTime currentUtcTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Store into a column of datatype `timestamp with time zone` in your SQL database. Retrieve back into an `OffsetDateTime`.

No need to involve your own time zone nor to convert between time zones.

(Code is not tested, forgive typos.)